# Combining 2 Not Like Statements in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a formula where I have a column for region and a column for district (a region is made up of districts), in the formula i have some pieces of code to exclude certain regions as a whole. But some i need to only exclude a few districts from some regions but not all. The where portion of the code looks like this: In the code I want to exclude all of Region 100 and region 76, but for region 88 I only want to exclude District 04 but when i type the code like this it stil excludes all of 88. (There is no GROUP BY in this code)

```
SELECT ID, Date, Class, Location, Training Number
FROM Table 1 INNER JOIN Table 2 ON Training Number     
WHERE (Region NOT LIKE '100') AND 
      (Region NOT LIKE '76') AND 
      (Region NOT LIKE '88') AND 
      (District NOT LIKE '04')
```

Comment: `LIKE` is expensive, and your query doesn't indicate that you actually need to use it. I would re-write this query using `<>` or `!=`

Comment: What are the datatypes here? `LIKE` without a wildcard isn't generally any more expensive than an `=` for a string column but if you are using it on numeric columns it will be.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I combine the not like so it only excludes district 04 in region 88 as opposed to excluding all of 88.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why you are using the `LIKE` operator, you should be able to use:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Class, Location, Training Number
FROM Table 1 
INNER JOIN Table 2 
  ON Training Number     
WHERE Region <> '100' 
  AND Region <> '76'
  AND 
  (
    Region <> '88' 
    OR District <> '04'
  );
```

Or you can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Class, Location, Training Number
FROM Table 1 
INNER JOIN Table 2 
  ON Training Number     
WHERE 
(
  Region NOT IN ('100', '76')
)
AND 
(
  Region <> '88' 
  OR District <> '04'
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fae0/1)

Comment: That worked thank you! And I am rewriting codes from access to sql and the previous code used NOT LIKE and LIKE and I didnt think to change it up.

Comment: @user1958651 typically `LIKE`/`NOT LIKE` are when matching parts of a string, etc. you would use a wildcard to match that value

Comment: @MikeChristensen I was testing and updated with a fiddle demo. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: @bernie it will still work with varchars -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fae0/1 -- I also updated the demo in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Class, Location, Training Number
FROM Table 1 INNER JOIN Table 2 ON Training Number     
WHERE (Region <> '100') AND -- Region cannot be 100
      (Region <> '76') AND  -- Region cannot be 76
      (Region <> '88' OR District <> '04') -- Region cannot be 88 if District is 04
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
where Region not in ('100', '76', '88') and district <> '04'
```

You don't need to use `like` for this.

Comment: But he *does* want District 04 for Regions other than 88 though.